# PHP custom profile url with router

Tags: php

So I recently made a custom router (view the first picture),
And I can't find anything about how to set a custom profile link (2nd picture)

If anyone knows how this would work, i'd appreciate it

[custom router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZggW.png)
[custom profile link in router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB18l.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You would not want to use a switch statement in order to redirect a custom profile link such as profile/{username} since it is a dynamic link. What you can do instead is in your router php file, assuming that you access $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], is have a function that detects if the request is a user profile link and then execute some code. Ideally you want to handle all dynamic link processing at either the top of the switch statement or bottom. Here is an example of how it would work:

```php
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//isProfileLink will be a function that detects if the url is a custom profile url
if( isProfileLink($request) ) {
    //getUsernameFromProfileLink will be a function that gets the username from the profile link
    $username = getUsernameFromProfileLink($request));
    require 'pages/profile.php?username=' . $username;
}

//Non-dynamic/Non-custom links handling here
switch ($request)
    case ...
```

And then in the profile.php, you have some sort of code set up that gets the username entered from $_GET['username'], and then assuming you have a database setup you would make a query to get the row in the users table where username=$_GET['username']. This will give you all the required user information, and then you can dynamically load HTML using PHP.